# Blocking threads in Python

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, pipe

I'm debugging some Python code which has a blocking issue. I have some hypothesis on the what is going on there, but I do not know Python thread mechanisms well enough to verify it.

Here is the code:

```
class Executor:

    def execute_many(commands):

        with_processes = zip(commands, seld.process_cycle)

        def write():
            for command, process in with_processes:
                send_command_to_process(process, command)

        writing_thread = threading.Thread(target=write)
        writing_thread.start()

        for _, process in with_processes:
            yield receive_result_from_process(process)

        thread.join()
```

and somewhere else:

```
foos = [make_foo(result) for result in executor.execute_many(commands)]
```

The `process_cycle` of `Executor` yields `subprocess.Popen` objects. The `send_command_to_process` and `receive_result_from_process` communicate with these processes by pipes.

The issue I'm debugging is that from time to time this code freezes: all `Popen` processes and the `writing_thread` are blocked on flushing after writing to the pipes.

I did not expect it to happen, since (even if buffers are full) the `execute_many` generator will `yield receive_result_from_process(process)` and unblock one of the processes (which does not happen - `execute_many` freezes inside the loop).

So I came up with a hypothesis, that if `writing_thread` is blocked by a full pipe buffer, the main thread is blocked too (they are in the same process).

Is that possible? If so it a Python feature, or Linux feature?

**TL;DR**

If a Python process has two threads and one of them is blocked on flushing after write to a full pipe buffer, could that block the other thread?

If so it a Python feature, or Linux feature?

Comment: Can you provide full program with the bug and instructions how to launch it?

Comment: Sorry, but not really. These locks happen only occasionally and only if the commands take a lot of time and flush a lot of data (they make requests actually). A minimum relevant subset of code does not block, and I cannot post the full code since it is my eployers property.

Comment: Maybe you can create some kind of mock-up, toy-example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one thread is blocked, other thread can continue execution for sure.

Comment: Thank you for that, it helped me to spot the actual bug.

Answer (score 2):

There is something called the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) in CPython which prevents python bytecode to be interpreted in different threads.

Each thread needs to actively release the thread so that another one can execute.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know about GIL. The question is: does a Python thread release the lock if it is blocked by a full pipe?